# Send data using curl

Tags: php, curl

Trying to send data to a server which accepts data in the following format
`VERIFY_DATA=MER_ID=xxx|MER_TRNX_ID=xxx| MER_TRNX_AMT=xxx`
Will the following lines do?

```
$datatopost="VERIFY_DATA=MER_ID=xxx|MER_TRNX_ID=xxx| MER_TRNX_AMT=xxx";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datatopost);<br />
```

Any help will be appreciated,I am new with curl.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [article](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl) to see how to do it properly.

I personally used this code to do it on a project of mine

```
$data="from=$from&to=$to&body=".urlencode($body)."&url=$url";   
//$urlx contains the url where you want to post. $data contains the data you are posting
//$resp contains the response.
        $process = curl_init($urlx); 

        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

        curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);

        $resp = curl_exec($process); 

        curl_close($process);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example in php. This asks for and returns an FX quote. My data request is in the URL yours is in the post-fields though so you need to adjust. It looks as though you have spaces in the data you are passing "x| ME" i suspect it will not like that.

```
$ch = curl_init(); // initialise CURL
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_opt_string ); // this contains the URL and the request 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // no header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "93.129.141.79"); // where to send the data back to / outgoing network
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); // tell it what the agent is
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // want the data back as a post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return as a string rather than to the screen
$output = curl_exec($ch); // varu=iable to return it to

curl_close($ch); // close cURL resource, and free up system resources

$subject = $output; // get the data
```

I constructed my output sting as follows

```
$curl_opt_string = "http://msxml.rexefore.com/index.php?username=MiJoee4r65&password=L8e44Y&instrument=245.20." . $lhsrhs . "LITE&fields=D4,D6";
```